# Flutter: Null check operator used on a null value, late keyword not working either

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to render a simple 10x10 grid of characters on my application, but the grid boxes are not being rendered properly (only the characters are being displayed, not the boxes themselves), and I'm getting an exception stating: Null check operator used on a null value. I have tried using the late keyword, but that gives me the exception "LateInitializationError: Field 'grid' has not been initialized." Any ideas on how to get around this would really help. Thanks!

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Grid? grid;
  List<String> selectedList = [];
  var isLoaded = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getData();
    super.initState();

  }

  getData() async{
    grid = await RemoteService().getGrid();
    if(grid!=null){
      print('Payload received');
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Wordsearch'),
      ),
      body: Visibility(
        visible: isLoaded,
        replacement: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for(var i=0;i<10;i++) Row(
              children: [
                for(var j=0;j<10;j++) GridItem(
                    item: grid!.grid[i][j],
                    isSelected: (bool value){
                      setState(() {
                        if(value){
                          selectedList.add(grid!.grid[i][j]);
                        } else{
                          selectedList.remove(grid!.grid[i][j]);
                        }
                      });
                    })
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "Null check operator used on a null value" is always a sign that you promised something would not ever ever be null with "!" and you broke your promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a FutureBuilder to await the async request

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Your Grid needs time to load, so if you run your build method immediatly, it will give you the null check error, because the grid is null.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't consider the time it would take to retrieve the data via an api call :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with targiasld, you should use a FutureBuilder if you are awaiting data.

Or if you want to await data and display after loaded, your grid assignment (i believe) needs to be in the setState call as well, and since you are doing that might as well use the grid having data to control visibility instead of a separate variable.

Also with your nested for loops i assume you are wanting a grid of widgets? There is a [GridView widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) which handles the building of the grid, which might fix the null checking.

I can provide code samples if that is needed

Comment: Thank you for the grid view suggestion! When I tried using it, I got caught up trying use a 2d list in the itembuilder, any pointers on how to use two indices for a gridview builder?

Comment: Hmm probably not an easy way to do that, would there be any way to clean/format the data into a single index array before it gets to the gridview.builder?